# Re-ordering array so n follows m

Tags: java, arrays

I'm being asked to reorder an array so that n follows every instance of m. I know that there are equal amounts of both n and m in the array. For example if 4 follows every 3

```
[3,2,2,4] = [3,4,2,2]
[1,3,1,4,4,3,1] = [1,3,4,1,1,3,4]
```

I've managed to be able to solve most cases for this question, except for a few in the examples above the second one works except for on the last 3. The way I wrote my code was to search the rest of the array for another 4, however it occurs before the last 3. Below is my code,

```
public static int[] reOrder(int[] arr) {
    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == 3) {
            for(int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if(arr[j] == 4) {
                    temp = arr[i+1];
                    arr[i+1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use separate pointers for 3's and 4's, keeping rightmost position of 4 in memory, so code should looks like this:

```
public static int[] reOrder(int[] arr) {
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == 3 && i != arr.length - 1 && arr[i+1] != 4) { // we need to do it only if successor isn't 4, and position isn't last
            while (j < arr.length && arr[j] != 4 || (j > 0 && arr[j-1] == 3)) { //searching for first unused '4' in array
                j++;
            }
            if (arr[j] == 4) {
                temp = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the array `{4, 3, 0, 3, 0, 4}`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've missed this point, you can check updated version.

Comment: I still get the same answer I got before (`[0, 3, 0, 3, 4, 4]`).

Comment: I've fixed one parenthesis thing, now it should work ok, while it's still unclear what to do if 3 stays in the rightmost position

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it in one line:

```
public static int[] reOrder(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr).filter(i -> i != 4)
        .flatMap(i -> i == 3 ? IntStream.of(3, 4) : IntStream.of(i))
        .toArray();
}
```

or better yet, parameterized:

```
public static int[] reOrder(int[] arr, int n, int m) {
    return IntStream.of(arr).filter(i -> i != n)
        .flatMap(i -> i == m ? IntStream.of(m, n) : IntStream.of(i))
        .toArray();
}
```

This works by streaming the ints to first remove all "n" values, then insert an "m" after every "n". This approach is safe given it is known that the count of n and m are the same.

The time complexity of this code is O(n) (ie it's one pass over the values), whereas your code is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: The question isn't entirely clear, but I think the 3s are meant to stay remain in the same positions. This does not give the OPs desired result for   `[1,3,1,4,4,3,1]`.

Comment: @Paul I noticed that too, but as no explanation was given for how the ending `1` in the second example magically transported itself, I assumed an error by OP.

Comment: @Pail but I see now that if only swaps were allowed, then that would explain it. The first example is unfortunate: if the two `2` values were different numbers, the question would be clearer, but as they are indistinguishable we can't see if the reordering was from swapping or inserting/shifting.